# $(A_n) _{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of events in a probability space. Express: At least one out of every 5 consecutive $A_n$'s occurs.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

$(A_n) _{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of events in a probability space ($\Omega , \mathcal{B}, P).$ Express the following event in terms of given events: At least one out of every 5 consecutive $A_n$'s occurs.

This should be a general question that probably does not include any calculations but requires understanding of the terms used.

I thought that maybe expressing the complement event (none of every 5 consequtive occurs) would be easier but could not find a way to continue with it. What makes this question more difficult for me is that I am finding it hard to decide how should I approach it as it includes an infinite number of events and a condition I have not seen before.

Comment: Start by expressing the condition "at least one out of $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5$ occurs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was 
$$\mathop{\cap}_{j=1}^\infty\left(\mathop{\cap}_{i=j}^{j+4}(A_i{}^{c})\right)^c$$

To unpack this a bit, $A_1^c \cap \dotsb \cap A_5^c$ is the event that none of those five consecutive events occur. The event that at least one of them occurs is $\left(A_1^c \cap \dotsb \cap A_5^c\right)^c$. Then I need this to be true wherever I start, so I need $\left(A_1^c \cap \dotsb \cap A_5^c\right)^c$ **and** $\left(A_2^c \cap \dotsb \cap A_6^c\right)^c$ **and** $\,\,\,\dotsb$

Comment: should the inner (A_j)^c be (A_i)^c?

Comment: @Zoltán Yes, thanks!

Comment: Would it not be easier to write $\cap_j \cup_{i=1}^{j+4} A_i$?